# How to declare multidimensional array of two different datatypes

Tags: go, multidimensional-array

I have List of Tuple in python as you see below:

```
data  = [
    (435347,'cat'),  
    (435347,'feline'),
    (435347,'lion'),
    (6765756,'dog'),
    (6765756,'hound'),
    (6765756,'puppy'),
    (435347,'kitten'),
    (987977,'frog')
    ]
```

how can i convert data into GO equivalent, I have googled it but everywhere they have specified with the same data-type of multidimensional array like this,

```
int_list := [4][2]int{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}

string_list := make([][]string, 0)

a := [1][2]string{{"lion","dog"}}
```

help me out..!

Updated:

for Mixed-type Collections of Array:

```
array := []interface{}{1, "dog", "lion", 12, 45.09, true, false}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two possible solutions here: actual multidimensional arrays of mixed data types (what you seem to be asking for) and arrays of structs (what you probably want).

#### Multidimensional arrays of mixed data-types using interfaces

If you really want to do multi-dimensional arrays of mixed types, you need to use interfaces:

```
interfaceArray := [2][2]interface{}{{1,"dog"},{2,"cat"}}
fmt.Println(interfaceArray)
```

Outputs:

> [[1 dog] [2 cat]]

Interfaces must be handled with care as they can be... anything. This means that there is no enforcement that the first argument is an int and the second is a string. I can just as easily add `{"lion", 3}` and the compiler will be happy, but your program will crash if it doesn't check the type first.

You can do [type conversions and assertions](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) on interfaces to ensure the correct data types.

#### Arrays of structured data

Putting python tuples in a list does not make it a multi-dimensional array. The closest equivalent in Go would be an array of structs.

```
type animal struct {
  id int
  name string
}

animalList := [2]animal{{1, "cat"}, {2, "dog"}}
fmt.Println(animalList)
```

Outputs:

> [{1 cat} {2 dog}]

In this case, the types are clearly defined, and I cannot store `{"lion", 3}` in the array.

**final note**: `[size]type` defines an array. `[]type` defines a slice. I'm using arrays here as this is what you mention in your question, but slices would be just as (or probably more) appropriate.

Comment: so there is no way to declare a multi-dimensional array of different datatype without using interface..? Why like this..?

Comment: There's almost never a way to do mixed-type multi-dimensional arrays without using something more generic (eg: a `void *` in C) that can represent anything. python doesn't have them either as tuples are not arrays, so you really have a list of tuples, not a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 8):

You can't create multi dimensional array with two different type. Better to use structure. Hope this will work for your purpose.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Data struct {
    i int
    s string
}

func main() {
    data := []Data{
        {435347,"cat"},
        {435347,"feline"},
        {435347,"lion"},
    }

    fmt.Println(data)
}
```